# UITableView Push to URL help

Tags: uitableview, push, nsurl

I am trying to push to a new view and send a url to the webview in that view but it's not getting the url request. storyLink is declared earlier on, but even if I try to request http://www.google.com it doesn't even work either, so I know the problem is it's not accepting the url for some reason.

```
DetailViewController *newviewController=[[[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:nil]autorelease];
            NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:storyLink]];
            [newviewController.rssview loadRequest:request];
            [self.navigationController pushViewController:newviewController animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

Better you declare a property in next view for NSURL and set the value from the parent view.

For example, set following code in your DetailViewController.h file

```
    @interface DetailViewController : UIViewController
    {
            NSURL *request;
    }
    @property (nonatomic, assign) NSURL *request;
```

In your DetailViewController.m file...
       @synthesize request;

And modify your current code as below...

```
    DetailViewController *newviewController=[[[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:nil]autorelease];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:storyLink]];
    newviewController.request = request;
    //[newviewController.rssview loadRequest:request];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:newviewController animated:YES];
```

**In reference to your code...:**

Following are some missing things that you have to modify in your code and it will start working fine.

1. Set delegate for UIWebview control.

   ```
   self.rssview.delegate = self;
   [self.rssview loadRequest:self.request];
   ```
2. In your DetailViewController.h, modify following lines.

   ```
   @interface DetailViewController : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate>
   {
       IBOutlet UIWebView *rssview;
       NSURLRequest *request;
   }
   @property(nonatomic, retain, readonly)UIWebView *rssview;
   @property (nonatomic, assign) NSURLRequest *request;
   @end
   ```
3. In DetailViewController.m add delegate method of UIWebview as given below...

   ```
   - (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)myWebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
   {
       return YES;
   }
   ```
4. Replace following code in

   ```
   - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
   {
       int storyIndex = [indexPath indexAtPosition: [indexPath length] - 1];
       NSString * storyLink = [[stories objectAtIndex: storyIndex] objectForKey: @"link"]; 
       // clean up the link - get rid of spaces, returns, and tabs...
       storyLink = [storyLink stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
       storyLink = [storyLink stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@""];
       storyLink = [storyLink stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
       storyLink = [storyLink stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy];
       NSLog(@"link: %@", storyLink);
       if(indexPath.row==0)
       {       
           DetailViewController *newviewController=[[[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:nil]autorelease];
           NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:storyLink]];
           //[newviewController.rssview loadRequest:request];
           newviewController.request = request;
           [self.navigationController pushViewController:newviewController animated:YES];
       }
       else 
       {   
           DetailViewController *newviewController=[[[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:nil]autorelease];
           NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:storyLink]];
           //[newviewController.rssview loadRequest:request];
           newviewController.request = request;
           [self.navigationController pushViewController:newviewController animated:YES];
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: It got rid of a few errors but it's still not loading anything in the UIWebView

Comment: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/24939871/OCVMobile.zip
here is the project if you'd like to look at it, it seems like no one can figure it out